# angular 4 typescript validation error Object literal may only specify known properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

my service

```
import {Account} from '../models/Account';

  export class AccountingService {
  domain: string = "http://localhost:3000/api";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  getAccounts(){
    return  this.http.get<Account[]>(`${this.domain}/accounts` )
              .map(res => res)
  }

  addAccount(newAccount:Account){
    return  this.http.post(`${this.domain}/accounts`,newAccount)
              .map(res=>res);
  }

  updateAccount(newAccount: Account){
    return this.http.put(`${this.domain}/accounts/${newAccount.id}`,newAccount)
              .map(res=>res);
  }

  deleteAccount(id){
    return  this.http.delete(`${this.domain}/accounts/${id}`)
              .map(res=>res);
  }
}
```

my model

```
export class Account{
    _id?: string;
    name: string;
    amount: number;

}
```

my component

```
import {AccountingService} from '../../services/accounting.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accounting',
  templateUrl: './accounting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accounting.component.css']
})
export class AccountingComponent implements OnInit {
  accounts:Account[];
  name:string;
  amount:number;
  constructor(private accountService : AccountingService ) {

    this.accountService.getAccounts()
      .subscribe(accounts =>{
        console.log(accounts);
      })

   }

   addAccount(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const newAccount : Account={
      name: this.name,
      amount: this.amount
    };

    this.accountService.addAccount(newAccount);
   }
```

getAccounts() works perfectly but addAccount function give me a

> error Object literal may only specify known properties and amount in does not exist in type Account

it may be a logical error but I do not know how to solve it in this moment

Comment: This looks like code that should work without any error: Can you provide Stackblitz example? Also check that you haven't misstyped any property :) also instead of exporting `class Account` try export `interface Account`

Comment: https://github.com/michelnovellino/angular-crud the repository on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1 -** You didn't have imported `Account` interface in your `AccountingComponent`.

Add `import { Account } from '../../models/Account';` in your 
`AccountingComponent`

**Problem 2 -** In your `AccountingService` the `addAccount` function have generic type `<Account>`, so you need to also define the type that you are returning from that method also as `Account` and not the default (which is `any`). You can solve this by setting type of the `res` as `Account`.

```
addAccount<Account>(newAccount:Account) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.domain}/accounts`,newAccount)
       .map((res: Account) => res);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have forgotten to make your service Injectable (and maybe haven't declared it in the provider list.